# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Freeze but can move mouse Help!

Tags: freeze

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed and, I left my computer downloading something and a few minutes later my computer freezes and I can still move my mouse but, Nothing would work Is there a way to fix this? And is this a Hardware problem? I have a HP Pavilion 500 223w and Geforce Graphics card (Forgot what model) Can anyone help? Thanks! In the logs it says Feb  5 15:33:31 tristan-500-223w org.gnome.ScreenSaver[2894]: ** (gnome-screensaver:3287): WARNING **: Couldn't get presence status: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: Did your pc freeze in the lock screen (password prompt), or regular window? Can you please add a screenshot, or explain the `freeze` a little better?

Comment: At the desktop I was logged in.

Comment: Well, just a few minutes ago I got some Graphical glitches then  it froze But I can still move my mouse.

Comment: A solution for me is to change in a Terminal (e.g. ctrl+alt+F1)
login as a normal user
doing *sudo lightdm restart" or "sudo lightdm force-reloade". Doing this way closes all open applications and i have to login again but I don't have to reboot the system.
Hope this may help a little

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a GPU hang. Your system may not be properly halting display services when sleep activates and that would result in a paused display. Ensure your drivers are up to date, and if possible, check for any listed bugs with that particular software revision. I *think* ctrl+alt+bckspc restarts the display+session manager, but I'm not sure what's different between Wayland and Xorg. Rebooting is my only *temporary* solution.

Comment: I tried installing some drivers but, I could not login after resulting in me reinstalling ubuntu. And, Could this GPU hang break my Computer? like having to hold down the power button in stead of shutting down (and I cannot when it freezes) Thanks!

Comment: A GPU hang won't harm your computer as it only involves display output, however hard shutdowns are a possible danger and the necessity to do so is unfortunate. In the case this isn't a GPU hang, I'd suggest checking your hardware's compatibility with Ubuntu. Does this issue only happen after leaving the system running for a while? Or does it happen at any time? If it's a random thing that occurs even during active use, it's likely more complicated than a display pause.

Comment: Well, It has not froze in a while now, It froze on me like 3 or 4 times. here is what the log says

Comment: Feb  5 20:33:56 tristan-500-223w org.gnome.ScreenSaver[3176]: ** Message: Lost the name, shutting down.
Feb  5 20:34:02 tristan-500-223w gnome-session[3321]: Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
Feb  5 20:34:03 tristan-500-223w systemd-timesyncd[2502]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Feb  5 20:34:05 tristan-500-223w org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3176]: ** (gvfsd:3237): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Failed to retrieve share list from

Comment: I'm certainly no expert, but just a few scans over this gives me the idea that the issue is suspend-resume. The machine isn't able to call the resume services properly after it sleeps/suspends. I don't know how to fix this. I'd suggest updating your system and using the tag fix-missing. Other than that, I'd just check to see if your power manager AND your screensaver are both trying to handle suspend. Disabling the screensaver is all I can really think of. For anything more advanced, I defer to the more complex knowledge of another forum user. Hope I was of some use.

Comment: My computer just got some graphical glitches and froze hmm..

Comment: I was also using my computer at the time of the freeze